# How to remove Aptana from Eclipse?

Tags: macos, eclipse, plugins

How do I remove Aptana from Eclispe 3.5.2 on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To remove a feature or plugin from Eclipse, open Eclipse and select "About Eclipse" from the "Help" menu.  Select the "Installation Details" button.  Be sure the "Installed Software" tab is selected.  Find "Aptana", or any other plugin you want to remove, from the list of installed software a select it, then click the "Uninstall..." button at the bottom.

Make sure you restart Eclipse after the uninstall completes.

Comment: Thanks for these instructions. I found the "Installation details" button under the Eclipse menu, and "About Eclipse SDK". Otherwise this worked like a charm.

Comment: This left me with a broken Eclipse and the aptane editors still in place.

Comment: still had to manually remove the jars in the plugin directory

Answer (score 1):

For me 'Uninstall' button is in disabled mode. I tried 'Revert' under Help>installation Details>Installation History tab.  that also not working.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the best is to simply install from scratch as I had some problems with uninstall, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

With @heavyd's technique, the `Uninstall...` button was not available.

Instead I did this (in Eclipse Kepler):

> Window -> Preferences -> Install/Update -> Uninstall or update
>   software that is already installed

Select "Installed Software" and pick the one you want to remove and select "Uninstall..."

(Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13361266/2791390))